# What is the difference in purpose between tf.py_function and tf.function?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

The difference between the two is muddled in my head, notwithstanding the nuances of what is eager and what isn't. From what I gather, the `@tf.function` decorator has two benefits in that

1. it converts functions into TensorFlow graphs for performance, and
2. allows for a more Pythonic style of coding by interpreting many (but not all) common-place Python operations into tensor operations, e.g. `if` into `tf.cond`, etc.

From the definition of `tf.py_function`, it seems that it does just #2 above. Hence, why bother with `tf.py_function` when `tf.function` does the job with a performance improvement to boot and without the inability of the former to serialize?

Answer (score 20):

They do indeed start to resemble each other as they are improved, so it is useful to see where they come from. Initially, the difference was that:

- `@tf.function` turns python code into a series of TensorFlow graph nodes.
- `tf.py_function` wraps an existing python function into a single graph node.

This means that `tf.function` requires your code to be relatively simple while `tf.py_function` can handle any python code, no matter how complex.

While this line is indeed blurring, with `tf.py_function` doing more interpretation and `tf.function` accepting lot's of complex python commands, the general rule stays the same:

- If you have relatively simple logic in your python code, use `tf.function`.
- When you use complex code, like large external libraries (e.g. connecting to a database, or loading a large external NLP package) use `tf.py_function`.

Comment: Is "`tf.py_function` can handle any python code" true? I think that, e.g., any code that does item assignment will fail.