# TensorFlow dataset .map() method not working for built-in tf.keras.preprocessing.image functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I load in a dataset as such:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ds = tfds.load(
    'caltech_birds2010',
    split='train',
    as_supervised=False)
```

And this function works fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def pad(image,label):
    return (tf.image.resize_with_pad(image,32,32),label)

ds = ds.map(pad)
```

But when when I try mapping a different built-in function

```
from tf.keras.preprocessing.image import random_rotation

@tf.function
def rotate(image,label):
    return (random_rotation(image,90), label)

ds = ds.map(rotate)
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'

This is not the only function giving me issues, and it happens with or without the `@tf.function` decorator.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would try using tf.py_function in here for the random_rotation. For eg:

```
def rotate(image, label):
    im_shape = image.shape
    [image, label,] = tf.py_function(random_rotate,[image, label],
                                     [tf.float32, tf.string])
    image.set_shape(im_shape)
    return image, label

ds = ds.map(rotate)
```

Although I think they do similar things here according to [What is the difference in purpose between tf.py_function and tf.function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61564748/what-is-the-difference-in-purpose-between-tf-py-function-and-tf-function), tf.py_function is more straightforward for executing python code through tensorflow even though tf.function has a performance advantage.